# unable to add input method to ibus on KDE anymore

Tags: kde, ibus

I have become a fan of iBus on KDE. It integrates what scim does with least amount of configuration.
But since I have added the some input methods. I have not been able to add any more.

So when I click on the ibus icon, I see this.

[image: ibus menu from the system tray]

And on clicking preferences I see the input methods on the ibus-preferences
[image: List of input methods on ibus-preferences]
But , I am unable to add another input method from the menu there. All the input methods are grayed out there. [image: Grayed out input methods list on ibus preferences input method tab]

How would I go about adding more input methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=821221

I.e. that is just bad UI design, the > are clickable.

As you can see here:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=821221#c10

it depends on the theme.

Comment: any suggested fixes and workarounds? I don't seem to find anything on the bug page.